# githubから本番サーバへの wordpress theme の反映について

Tags: git, wordpress, github, amazon-ec2

githubから本番サーバへの反映は
どのような方法がお勧めでしょうか。

現在ローカルの開発環境で
vagrant
virtualbox
centos
のような形でウェブサイトの構築を行っています。
サーバはさくらスタンダードとAWSの2つのパターンがあります。
(EC2は現在インスタンス2つ、ゆくゆくはオートスケーリングを考えています。)
wordpressサイトの更新が主で、themeファイルのみを
git管理にしようと現在ワークフローを改善中です。

最近ようやくgithubをさわりはじめ
ローカルからリモートのリポジトリにpushすることはできました。
色々書籍などを見ていてもあまり載っていなかったのが
リモートリポジトリから本番環境に反映させる方法で
みなさんどのような環境で作業しているのかをお伺いしたく書かせていただいています。

ワークフローとしてはgithubにpushした段階で最終確認
そのあと公開という流れになるかと思いますが
どのようなツールを使われていますか？

自分なりに考えてみたことを書かせていただきます。
・手動で反映するなら本番サーバにリモートリポジトリを設置して本番サーバ上でpull
・自動で反映するならスクリプトやツールを使う
こちらも認識違いやセキュリティリスクなど突っ込んでいただけましたら幸いです。

基本的には添付ファイルのAパターンが多いと思いますが
Bパターンでの運用をされている方もいらっしゃいますでしょうか。
メリットデメリットなど伺えましたら幸いです。
[image: githubから本番サーバへの反映]

Answer (score 2):

ワークフローをある程度自動化したいということで良いでしょうか。
そうであればいくつか方法が考えられます。またWordpressとのことでPHPを中心に考えます。

- Githubのwebhook
- CI/CDサービス
- デプロイツール

### Githubのwebhook

githubを利用されているとのことなので、[webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)の利用が可能です。Github上のイベントを起点に本番サーバへ通知、通知を受け取ったらpullさせます。無事デプロイが成功しているかどうかの処理も記述する必要があるので少し手間な点から今回の場合あまりオススメしません。

### Continuous Integration/Continuous Deployment サービス

- [Continuous Integration | StackShare](https://stackshare.io/continuous-integration)
- [Continuous Deployment | StackShare](https://stackshare.io/continuous-deployment)

どちらも今回の課題の守備範囲にはありますが、CDサービスの方が近いかと思います。具体的には[Buddy](https://buddy.works/)がサポートの方も親切で良かったです。
管理画面が必要であれば検討の余地はあると思います。

### デプロイツール

[Deployer — Deployment Tool for PHP](https://deployer.org/)
描かれている図の構成とは直接Githubが関わらなくなるという点で、少し変わりますがこちらもオススメです。

Comment: 様々なツールがあるんですね！ありがとうございます！当方英語が弱いのでwebhookから調べてみたいと思います。こちらの記事を参考にテストしてみたいと思いますhttp://qiita.com/oyas/items/1cbdc3e0ac35d4316885
参考になりました。ありがとうございますm(_)m

Comment: なるほど、では作者の方が日本人のツールで[Altax](http://kohkimakimoto.github.io/altax/ja/)というものがあるのでよければこちらも参照してみてください。

Comment: 度々のご紹介ありがとうございます！こちらも読ませていただきますm(_)m